# How do I run an github-imported android application on android studio

Tags: android, github, android-studio, open-source

So before I say anything, I am a total noob to android, but I am way to curious to figure out how to run this open source application that was built for a hackathon. ( https://github.com/android-fanatic/CosmosBrowserAndroid )

They dont have an APK, so I couldn't try it, but I really want to try it out. But every time I try to import the application into android studios, I get this message:

> Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> - The project 'CosmosBrowserAndroid-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>     Open Gradle wrapper file
> - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>     Apply Gradle plugin

And thus, I can't try the application out. Could anyone give me a step by step solution?

Comment: How about trying to change the `runProguard false` inside the `build.gradle` file to `minifyEnabled false` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the github project to a folder. Open Android Studio. Go to File->Import Project. Then choose the specific project you want to import and then click Next->Finish. It will build the Gradle automatically and'll be ready for you to use.

P.S: In some versions of Android Studio a certain error occurs-
error:package android.support.v4.app does not exist.
To fix it go to Gradle Scripts->build.gradle(Module:app) and the add the dependecies:

```
dependencies {      
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
}
```

Then start an emulator and run your app

For more information:
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html

Comment: I am still getting the same error... :/ 


`Error:(17, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'CosmosBrowserAndroid-master' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>`

Did it work for you? When I try it on other projects, it runs fine...